# Rebus - Send delayed message to another queue (Azure ServiceBus)

Tags: azure, rebus

I have a website and and a webjob, where the website is a oneway client and the webjob is worker.

I use the Azure ServiceBus transport for the queue.

I get the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot use ourselves as timeout manager
>   because we're a one-way client

when I try to send Bus.Defer from the website bus.

Since Azure Servicebus have built in support for timeoutmanager should not this work event from a oneway client?

The documentation on Bus.Defer says: Defers the delivery of the message by attaching a  header to it and delivering it to the configured timeout manager endpoint
    ///             (defaults to be ourselves). When the time is right, the deferred message is returned to the address indicated by the  header."

Could I fix this by setting the ReturnAddress like this:

```
headers.Add(Rebus.Messages.Headers.ReturnAddress, "webjob-worker");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could I fix this by setting the ReturnAddress like this: headers.Add(Rebus.Messages.Headers.ReturnAddress, "webjob-worker");

Yes :)

The problem is this: When you `await bus.Defer` a message with Rebus, it defaults to return the message to the input queue of the sender.

When you're a one-way client, you don't have an input queue, and thus there is no way for you to receive the message after the timeout has elapsed.

Setting the return address fixes this, although I admit the solution does not exactly reek of elegance. A nicer API would be if Rebus had a `Defer` method on its routing API, which could be called like this:

```
var routingApi = bus.Advanced.Routing;

await routingApi.Defer(recipient, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), message);
```

but unfortunately it does not have that method at the moment.

To sum it up: Yes, setting the return address explicitly on the deferred message makes a one-way client capable of deferring messages.

Comment: Is this a feature that could be added into Rebus? If so should I create an issue at the GitHub repo?

Comment: Well, I thought about that – but then I was in doubt about where it should be added, and also wondered what to call it..... for now, I suggest you add it by creating an extension method on `IBus` that accepts the destination queue as an argument